# Como compilar um arquivo *.c com o clang para que ele sinalize os problemas?

Tags: c, linux, compilação

No GCC eu digitava no terminal:

```
gcc -wall -o nomedoarquivo.c nomedoexecutavel
```

ou se só tivesse 1 arquivo .c [OBS.: digitava "a" para facilitar no nomedoexecutavel]:

```
gcc -wall -o *.c a
```

A restrição que eu utilizava, se houver no código a biblioteca `math.h`, tinha que acrescentar `-lm` no código. Aí ficaria assim:

```
gcc -wall -o *.c a -lm
```

**Como devo digitar para compilar o mesmo arquivo utilizando o *Clang* para que apareçam os problemas no código? Tem alguma restrição?**

Comment: `clang -Weverything ...` mas nao te queixes que dá avisos demais :)

Comment: Utilizo todas as flags do gcc no clang. Até agora não tive nenhum problema, gostaria de saber se houver algum.

Answer (score 4):

O clang é construído de forma bastante modularizada de forma que o processador da linha de comando (chamado **driver**) é completamente separado do compilador em si. Existem basicamente dois drivers. Um que tem interface idêntica ao GCC e outro, bem mais recente, que simula as ferramentas do MSVC.

Isso significa que tudo que você precisa fazer é `s/gcc/clang/g`. Todas as opções do gcc funcionarão sem problemas. Para reportar uma saudável quantidade de alertas use `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: +1 "uma saudável quantidade de alertas" :)

Answer (score 3):

o parâmetro é **-Wall**

eu uso -o em uma ordem diferente da que vc está usando. Acho que no final fica mais claro.

```
clang -Wall nomedoarquivo.c -o nomedoexecutavel

clang -Wall *.c -o a

clang -Wall *.c -lm -o a
```